# I cannot see the cookie in browser devtools Application/cookie

Tags: node.js, cookies, next.js, jwt, server-side-rendering

I am using nextJs13.2 with NodeJs Backend seperate server
While Authenticating with username and password I set the cookie from the backend nodeJS server

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const SignToken = id => {
    return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES});
}

const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now()+process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    httpOnly: true
}

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') cookieOptions.secure = true


const CreateSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = SignToken(user._id);

    res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);

    res
       .status(statusCode)
       .json({
        status: 'Success',
        token,
        data: {
            user
        }
       }) 
}
```

Then I am calling a controller to log in with the cookie

```
exports.login = catchAsync(async(req, res, next) => {
const { email, password } = req.body;

//Check if user exists
if(!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password', 400));
}

//Check if user Exists
const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

if(!user || !(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))){
    return next(new AppError('Invalid e-mail or password', 401))
}
    


CreateSendToken(user, 200, res);
});
```

Then in the login component am requesting a post method with credentials and in the handle submit function

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Send a POST request to the backend
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/users/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      // Redirect to the home page if the login is successful
      window.location.href = '/route/inventory';
    } else {
      // Display an error message if the login is unsuccessful
      const data = await response.json();
      setError(data.message);
    }
  };
```

I get everything even the localStorage is being Updated with everything but my cookie tab is left empty but I see that 'cookie used by frames from `localhost:3000` which is the port of my NextJS app' (the server host is of port 5000 where my cookie is initiated)

I know that nextJS uses SSR so my browser doesnot interract directly to my backend Node server rather it interacts with the nextJS server first.

but it failes to send a cookie to my browser i dont know what to do need help

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the cookie in your backend Node server, but you're trying to access it from your Next.js frontend application. Set the cookie in your Next.js application instead of your backend Node server.

```
import { setCookie } from 'nookies';

const handleLogin = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    const data = await response.json();

    // Set the cookie using the `nookies` library
    setCookie(null, 'jwt', data.token, {
      maxAge: data.expiresIn,
      path: '/',
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      sameSite: 'strict',
    });

    // Redirect to the home page
    router.push('/home');
  } else {
    const data = await response.json();
    setError(data.message);
  }
};
```

Nookie is a cookie helpers for Next.js